# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when using @dynamic with Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a NSManagedObject subclass (SOCommand*), and I'm trying to set properties of an instance of it using the following code:

```
    SOCommand* newCommand = [[SOCommand alloc]init];
    newCommand.commandName = self.tf_commandName.text;
    newCommand.sshCommand = self.tf_sshCommand.text;
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SOCommand setCommandName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I thought changing the prewritten `@dynamic` to `@synthesize` would solve it. While it did resolve this error, it led to other ones since `@dynamic` is required for Core Data. How am I supposed to set its properties? I read somewhere that you have to initialize `NSManagedObjects` in a special way, but that involved "adding" to the database, so I'm really confused.

Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not showing enough code to validate this, but I suspect you are making one of several common mistakes.

Common Problem #1: Not setting up your Managed Object Model Correctly
I can't demonstrate this in code, but your managed object model must contain each property you want. Just adding a new `@property` declaration in the object subclass does not add it to the model. It must exist in both places.

Common Problem #2: Implementing a Getter/Setter and calling Super

```
- (void)setCommandName:(NSString *)commandName
{
    // Do "willUpdateCommandName" logic here

    //Call Super
    [super setCommandName:commandName];

    // Do "didUpdateCommandName" logic here
}
```

This is a fairly common construction outside CoreData, but within Core Data, it is a common problem. Instead, you should call the primitive setter.

```
- (void)setCommandName:(NSString *)commandName
{
    // Do "willUpdateCommandName" logic here

    //Call Super
    [self setPrimitiveCommandName:commandName];

    // Do "didUpdateCommandName" logic here
}
```

Common Problem #3: You are initializing your object with `-init`, rather than `-initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`.

You are definitely making this mistake in your code sample, but possibly others too. [According to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/setPrimitiveValue%3aforKey%3a), you should not use `-init`. Internally, I suspect that it requires the NSEntityDescription to dynamically generate the getters/setters for your object.

If you don't want the object inserted immediately, you can pass `nil` as the `NSManagedObjectContext`, but you must pass in the `NSEntityDescription`, acquired from your `NSManagedObjectModel`. Doing this correctly looks like this.

```
// Macro for easy reading/writing
#define SOClass(x) NSStringFromClass([x class])
// It is important to note that the entity name *CAN* be different from the class name, but generally it is not
NSString *entityName = SOClass(SOCommand);
NSDictionary *entities = self.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName;
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = entities[entityName];
SOCommand *newCommand = [[SOCommand alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription 
                           insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

If you know the context you want to use, you may also use this syntax:

```
// Macro for easy reading/writing
#define SOClass(x) NSStringFromClass([x class])
// It is important to note that the entity name *CAN* be different from the class name, but generally it is not
NSString *entityName = SOClass(SOCommand);
SOCommand *newCommand = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName 
                                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely refer to this in the future. Future readers of this post will greatly benefit from this as well.

Answer (score 7):

you should insert new CoreData object by using:

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SOCommand" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

the way you init `SOCommand` cause this error .

Comment: Agree with @johnMa, it's the right way to create/insert a new core data object, and you must do like that every time.

Comment: That's creates and initialises the object, you then need to set its properties.  So the line above replaces your [[alloc]init] line.